# Push Git changes to perforce

Tags: git, perforce

There are usually questions about how to push perforce changes into git repo, generally about perforce to git workflow, but no the other way around.

There is Unreal Engine repository on GitHub. I have perforce server. 
Currently I have setup Perforce workspace in the same folder as to where I keep unreal engine sources.

Now I want to periodically do pull changes from Unreal git repo, and have them automatically reflected on perforce. (like new files, changes etc). Don't really care about reflecting history or commit names. Just to add all changed/new files from git to perforce, and for perforce to automatically pick it, without me manually going trouch each file and adding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map a Perforce workspace to your local git repo (exclude relevant `.git` type paths from the view), and run `p4 reconcile` to pick up current changes.

So the workflow is:

```
git pull
p4 reconcile
p4 submit
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought about doing it this way, but wasn't sure if that is going be good solution.

Comment: It's possible to craft solutions where you'd carry over more of the commit history, but given that you don't care about the history and just want the head revisions, I don't think it gets any easier than running those two commands.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use git-p4 to do this.

Create an empty branch in Perforce, add one file (can't clone empty directories; don't  clash with anything from git) and then clone it with git-p4.

```
$ git p4 clone //depot/your_area
$ cd your_area
```

Now you can add your git repo as a remote, and then cherry-pick all of the commits into your new repo:

```
$ git remote add your_git_repo /path/to/git/repo
$ git fetch your_git_repo
$ git cherry-pick ..your_git_repo/master
```

Assuming you already have a Perforce client area mapping `//depot/your_area`, you can now submit:

```
$ git p4 submit
```

At this point your git changes will have all shown up in Perforce as individual Perforce changelists. You can probably write a small script to then incrementally import new changes.